# Hyperbolic polynomials and group representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, polynomials

Recall that a homogeneous polynomial $P\in{\mathbb R}[X_1,\ldots,X_d]$ of degree $n$ is **hyperbolic** in the direction of a vector $V\ne0$ if for every vector $W$, the univariate polynomial $t\mapsto P(W+tV)$ has $n$ real roots. Notice that $P(V)$ must be non-zero, and we may assume w.l.o.g. that $P(V)>0$. The notion of hyperbolic polynomials is due to L. Garding, because of hyperbolic PDEs. He proved, among other things, that the connected component of $V$ in $\{P(W)>0\}$ is a convex cone (the cone of *future* in terms of evolutionary PDEs), and that $P$ is hyperbolic in every direction $V'$ of this cone. This is reminiscent to special relativity.

Examples of hyperbolic polynomials include

- $P=X_1\cdots X_d$, where $n=d$ and $V$ can be taken as $(1,\ldots,1)$
- $P(S)=\det S$, where $d=\frac{n(n+1)}2$ and ${\mathbb R}^d$ identifies with the space of symmetric matrices with real entries. Then $V=I_n$ and one uses the fact that eigenvalues of symmetric matrices are real. One may replace real symmetric by complex hermitian matrices, with $d=n^2$ instead.

Besides, let me recall a result of I. Schur about (generalized) permanents: let $H$ be a subgroup of ${\frak S}_n$, and $\chi$ be a complex character over $H$. Then, for every $S\in SPD_n$, one has
$$\chi(e)\det S\le d_\chi(S):=\sum_{g\in H}\chi(g)\prod_{i=1}^ns_{ig(i)}.$$
In particular, the connected component of $I_n$ in $d_\chi>0$ contains the cone $SPD_n$.
This suggest that some of the $d_\chi$'s could be hyperbolic in the direction of $I_n$. This is true at least in the following cases:

- $H=\frak S_n$ and $\chi=\epsilon$ the signature, where $d_\chi=\det$,
- $H=(e)$, where $d_\chi(S)=\prod_i s_{ii}$ (remark that the corresponding Schur's inequality is known has *Hadamard inequality*),

  In between, when $H$ is the natural inclusion of ${\frak S}_m\times\cdots\times{\frak S}_q$ with $m+\cdots+q\le n$, and $\chi$ is the product of the signatures, then $d_\chi$ is the product of hyperbolic polynomials of the types above, hence is itself hyperbolic.

However, the choice $H={\frak S}_n$ and $\chi={\bf 1}$ yields the permanent, which is not hyperbolic in the direction of $I_n$ if $n\ge2$.

> My question is whether there are other hyperbolic polynomials among the $d_\chi$'s. If so, how do they classify ? Does hyperbolicity correspond to a classical property of $(H,\chi)$ ?

Answer (score 4):

[EDIT]: Recently, I ran into this question again, so decided to undelete this 3 year old answer of mine.

---

Although not an answer to the exact question, I thought it worth mentioning an important problem where characterizing certain situations where the permanent leads to a hyperbolic polynomial was an open problem for many years. Details follow below.

> (**Defn.**) Let $A$ be a square real matrix. We say that an $n \times n$ real matrix $A$ is *column monotone* if it has weakly decreasing entries in each column (when reading downwards). That is, $a_{ij} \ge a_{i+1,j}$ for all $1 \le i \le n-1$ and $1\le j \le n$.

Based on this definition, (**MCPC**) The *Monotone Column Permanent Conjecture* of Haglund, Ono, Wagner ("Theorems and conjectures involving rook polynomials with only real zeros", Kluwer, 1999), is as follows.

> (**Erstwhile conjecture**). If $A$ is an $n \times n$ column monotone matrix, then $\text{per}(A+zJ)$ is a polynomial in $z$ that has only real roots, where the *direction* $J$ is an $n \times n$ matrix of all ones.

This conjecture was proved in its full generality in ["Proof of the Montone Column Permanent Conjecture"](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.2565) by Brändén, Haglund, Visontai, and Wagner (2010).

My summary above is taken from the abovecited paper. If I find anything related to immanants, I'll update my answer.